# Polygons vs MultiPolygons in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

Is there an advantage to work with Polygons versus MultiPolygons in Google Earth Engine? I need to subdivide a region of interest into many sub-areas for which I will calculate the evolution of some variable. In GEE you can draw many different polygons and then repeat the operation but you can also define a MultiPolygon but I don't see the benefits of doing it. As an example, I'm calculating the mean of the values of B (a collection of images filtered by dates) over time.

```js
    var C = Chart.image.series(B, MultiPolygon, ee.Reducer.mean(),
    1000, 'system:time_start');
    print(C);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Multipolygon, the polygons are part of the same structure and share the same projection and polarity.

Earth Engine can perform the same operations on a ee.Geometry.MultiPolygon as  a ee.Geometry.Poygon, e.g. calculate the area, bounds, centroid, etc.

So use whatever is convenient for your application.

Comment: I have an example where I don't know how to proceed. A Multipolygon has one feature only, and I want to: 1. add labels to each polygon of a Multipolygon (consisting of a bunch of buffers), 2. download time series of a reducer for each polygon (the average sea surface temperature in each polygon). https://code.earthengine.google.com/c22f5f5c1fa795c74e9f8a1311d8817a

Comment: The Multipolygon does not have a feature, its the other way around. "add labels to each polygon" suggests adding each polygon to a FeatureCollection with a Feature for each polygon and each point.  Each feature holds the label as a property. Then reduce the feature collection according to the labels. Perhaps ask a new question if this is not helpful.

Comment: Thanks. Helps a lot but I'm trying to figure out how to make it work. Posting a new question.