# Polygons vs MultiPolygons in Google Earth Engine, labelling and reducing for each Feature

Tags: google-earth-engine

This question is a specific application of a [previous question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/250431/polygons-vs-multipolygons-in-google-earth-engine)

I want to:

1. Generate different groups of polygons (each belonging to a zone)
2. Each polygon inside a zone would have a label that indicates which zone it belongs to.
3. Then download a time series of the average (or any reducer) for EACH polygon. This time series should have a label that tells me what zone the polygon belongs to.

The way I tried to do this is by constructing a MultiPolygon (a set of buffers around points in my example) and then adding a label to the FeatureCollection they belong to. However, when I download the time series, I get (naturally) the average across polygons and not the average for each polygon.

I believe what I need to do is to turn the MultiPolygon into a FeatureCollection of Polygons, each with the same label...

Please see the code which has the example:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/0ed71b7645f904ab1c2a61ec10e7b548

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You indeed cannot set properties to multipolygons, only to individual features. Therefore, you will need to build a feature of each polygon. To answer this question you actually ask:

> I believe what I need to do is to turn the MultiPolygon into a
>   FeatureCollection of Polygons, each with the same label...

```
//  Make a feature collection of the inputs
var fc = ee.FeatureCollection([geometry, geometry2, geometry3, geometry4, geometry5]);

// set type of geometry to each feature
fc = fc.map(function(feat){
  return ee.Feature(feat).set('type', ee.Feature(feat).geometry().type());
});

// rearrange the multipolygons into polygons
var onlyPolys = fc.map(function(feat){
  feat = ee.Feature(feat);
  var geometries = feat.geometry().geometries(); // return a list of each geometry
  var extractPolys = ee.FeatureCollection(geometries.map(function(poly){
    poly = ee.Geometry.Polygon(ee.Geometry(poly).coordinates());
    return ee.Feature(poly).copyProperties(feat);
  }));
  return extractPolys;
}).flatten();

print(onlyPolys)
```

See [the link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/93a7ceb3011dc6dfb2dbf566963311b4) for the sample feature collection I draw.

Comment: Dear Kuik, your link is not working