# Area of MultiPolygon including all the holes inside the polygon - Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am facing a very simple problem but my code is getting very complex. There must be some simple solution for this. That's why I am posting.

Problem:
I have a MultiPolygon. In this Multipolygon I have some polygons containing holes (some may not). I want to find the area of the holes and thus find the total area of MultiPolygon including the holes. (i.e.,  Area of outershell of all polygons.)
Is there any simple solution to get the area of Multipolygon including the hole area?

P.S.
This is a simplified version of my problem. In real problem threre are thousands of polygons inside the multipolygon which is the result of `reduceToVectors`. I know the first coordinate list item of a polygon is the outer shell and all the rest list items are inner hollow shells.

Link to my code
https://code.earthengine.google.com/fd058b8d3864dfec0d1efab741a24a15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If two conditions you assume are met, you can use the following code to calculate the area. Namely: 1) all geometries of your multipolygon are Polygons and 2) the first coordinate list item of a polygon with holes is the outer shell.

```
// get a list of areas of each polygon
var areaTot = myMultiPoly.geometries()  // get all geometries in a list 
          .map(function(geom){ // map over each geometry (either multi or single)
            var coords = ee.Geometry(geom).coordinates(); // get the coordinates

            // if there is one geometry, calculate it's area
            var area = ee.Number(ee.Algorithms.If(coords.length().eq(1),
                                                  ee.Geometry(geom).area(),

            // if there are multiple geometries (list of coordinates longer than 1),
            //  calculate the area of the first 
                  ee.Geometry.Polygon(coords.get(0)).area() // get area first geometry
            ));
            return area;
          }).reduce(ee.Reducer.sum()); // sum all areas in the list


print('list of areas of each polygon',areaTot)
```

If you are also intrested in each area of each polygon which forms a hole, analyse the lowest part of [the link to the code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/aa4148741babeaaf49d93f54a895a923). If there are also point or other types of geometries in the geometry collection, [consider setting the a geometryType property](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/319269/polygons-vs-multipolygons-in-google-earth-engine-labelling-and-reducing-for-eac) to each feature, and filtering out the types of geometries you are interested in.

Comment: My solution was also like this map inside condition inside map. Thanks. var areas = function(feature) {
  var myFeatureList = ee.List(feature)
  var conditionalAreas = ee.Algorithms.If(myFeatureList.length().gt(1), 
                myFeatureList.map(function(feature1) {
                    var area1 = ee.Geometry.Polygon(feature1).area(1);
                    return area1;
                }),
                ee.Geometry.Polygon(myFeatureList).area(1)
              )
  return conditionalAreas            
};

Comment: Dear Kuik, your link is not working

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
ee.Geometry.MultiPolygon(
  myMultiPoly.geometries().map(function (geometry) {
    return ee.Geometry(geometry).dissolve(1)
  })
)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/a92ce7f5f09bcd6c66b111cc78345671

Comment: Sorry, may be I am not clear with my question.. I wand to find the area of the hole. Since myMultiPoly is created from the difference of geometry2. hence I know that my hole area is area of geometry2. ConvexHull will not work since it creates a simplified version of polygon. I want the area including the holes not without holes. Thank you updated code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/2770883b38c02ad9de60d0fda8958da3