# Computation timed out for multipolygon but not for single polygon of equivalent size in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am currently running a GEE code and have been encountering this issue repeatedly:

For geometries composed of a single polygon, or a MultiPolygon that is relatively grouped together, the computation runs without any issues. However, when running the same code for a MultiPolygon that is spread-out (i.e. several parcels distributed across a large country), the computation times out. Both geometries have similar sizes (about 15,000 hectares) and the reducers are being calculated at a similar scale (about 600 m) yet only the latter fails.

Is this due to how voids are processed? If not, what is causing this discrepancy?

I can't share the actual code because of IP rights, but I've tried to recreate the error through an MRE (disclaimer: I know it's an outrageous calculation, it's just meant to illustrate the question I am asking here)

Link to code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/2ed983b80081bdce9097cef9d16e08b5

```
print('area in hectares', geometry.area(ee.ErrorMargin(10)).divide(10000).floor());
print('area2 in hectares', geometry2.area(ee.ErrorMargin(10)).divide(10000).floor());

var input = ee.Image("ESA/GLOBCOVER_L4_200901_200912_V2_3").select('landcover');
Map.addLayer(input, {}, 'Landcover');

var randomComputation1 = input.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.frequencyHistogram(),
  geometry: geometry,
  scale: 1,
  maxPixels: 1e11
});
print(randomComputation1);

var randomComputation2 = input.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.frequencyHistogram(),
  geometry: geometry2,
  scale: 1,
  maxPixels: 1e11
});
print(randomComputation2);
```

Comment: You need to post an example.

Comment: I hadn't because of IP rights, but I managed to create a MRE which I've added now

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to work with `reduceRegions()` instead of `reduceRegion()` and for that you need to change your handdrawn multipolygon into a `featureCollection()` as is explained in this answer: [Polygons vs MultiPolygons in Google Earth Engine, labelling and reducing for each Feature](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/319269/polygons-vs-multipolygons-in-google-earth-engine-labelling-and-reducing-for-eac)

```
var fc = ee.FeatureCollection([geometry2]);
print(fc, 'fc')

var onlyPolys = fc.map(function(feat){
  feat = ee.Feature(feat);
  var geometries = feat.geometry().geometries(); // return a list of each geometry
  var extractPolys = ee.FeatureCollection(geometries.map(function(poly){
    poly = ee.Geometry.Polygon(ee.Geometry(poly).coordinates());
    return ee.Feature(poly).copyProperties(feat);
  }));
  return extractPolys;
}).flatten();

print(onlyPolys, 'onlyPolys')
```

Then you should be able to work with the featureCollection:

```
var randomComputation2 = input.reduceRegions({
  collection: onlyPolys,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.frequencyHistogram(),
  scale: 250
});
print(randomComputation2);
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/eddb6217f08acf21c5423e5dba1e6900

Comment: It's an interesting work-around, but it doesn't really answer the question since now I have reduced each polygon separately though i need the statistics for each multipolygon as one, aggregating the results then would be different depending on the reducer so it's not a solution that fits all

Comment: Sorry but then you just have to be clearer in your question what you want, because it doesnt make sense. You want the entire area that encompasses the different elements of the multipolygon (use bounds)? Or you want only to use the pixels that are in the different polygons?

Comment: I want to reduce the different elements of the multipolygon as one ensemble, hence why I am passing them as a single geometry. In my example randomComputation2 returns only one result, not one result per each part of the multipolygon.